# Change MS SQL Server database size from Powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I need to use Powershell to automate changing the size of a database on an MS SQL 2014 instance.

Currently, we perform the following manual steps.

1. Open SQL Server Management Studio
2. Connect to instance
3. Right-click, click Properties on a Database
4. Select `Files` page
5. Double the `Initial Size` value for both `ROWS Data` and `LOG` database files

How could this action be performed with Powershell?

Powershell remoting is not required. This can be performed from the SQL server host.

Answer (score 0):

I was expecting to modify a Powershell object. So I overlooked the obvious solution of invoking a SQL query from Powershell.

This is done with the `Invoke-Sqlcmd` cmdlet.

I found the following query online and modified it for my scenario.

```
USE master;
GO
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2012 
MODIFY FILE
    (NAME = test1dat3,
    SIZE = 20MB);
GO
```

The files to be modified are `MOM_DATA` and `MOM_LOG`. The query spans multiple lines, so I put it in a separate file called `change_db_size.sql`.

I executed the query as follows.

`Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile "change_db_size.sql" -ServerInstance "SERVERNAME\INSTANCENAME"`